# MongoDB Yaml config file Unrecognized Option:Storage

Tags: mongodb, cmd, yaml

We are trying to set up mongodb's remote access by using a config file, and are having trouble running the config file in the bin folder. 
When we put our script through YAML Lint it says its valid, but when we run our file in command prompt it interchanges two errors 1) Unrecognized Option: Storage and 2) Unrecognized Option: SystemLog

```
This is our config file
storage: 
  dbPath: C:\\data\\db
  enabled: true
systemLog: 
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  logpath: C:\\data\\log\\mongo.log
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

our command in command prompt is

```
mongod -f mongo.config.txt
```

Please Help <3

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of errors in your config (for MongoDB 3.2):

- There is no `storage.enabled` option, I think you meant `storage.journal.enabled`
- There is no `systemLog.logpath` option, this should be `systemLog.path`

This modified config file seems to work as expected:

```
storage: 
  dbPath: C:\\data\\db
  journal:
    enabled: true
systemLog: 
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: C:\\data\\log\\mongo.log
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

You can browse for more options in the [Configuration File Options page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/)

Answer (score 2):

This happen due to invalid yaml syntax. In my case, i missed the space between dbPath and value

**Incorrect**

```
storage:
    dbPath:"./data/db"
```

**Correct**

```
storage:
    dbPath: "./data/db"
```

Answer (score 2):

Now in updated mongod, **enabled** key is not present. so try removing enabled and journal key as below

```
storage: 
  dbPath: C:\\data\\db
systemLog: 
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: C:\\data\\log\\mongo.log
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

This happened with me because I deleted a space in the configuration file.

```
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongo
  journal:
    enabled: true
```

I got this error, when the configuration file had the below state, note the gap before **enabled**:

```
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongo
  journal:
  enabled: true
```