# Unrecognized option:storage when starting mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I installed mongodb on Ubuntu and the `/etc/init/mongod.conf` looks like the following:-

```
# mongod.conf

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /data/var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true

#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /data/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

I get the error when running

```
sudo mongod -f  /etc/init/mongod.conf
```

Error message:

> Unrecognized option: storage

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39607107/mongodb-yaml-config-file-unrecognized-optionstorage) seems like a similar issue caused by syntaxes though. It doesn't seem I have those issues in my `mongod.conf` file. Appreciate any insight!

Answer (score 0):

Actually mongoDB works when I edit this not in **etc/init/mongod.conf** but in **etc/mongod.conf**