# mongodb.conf not working with YAML syntax

Tags: mongodb

I am on a Windows 10 laptop and installed mongodb 4.4 recently. But when I run mongod, I thought it uses the mongodb.cfg file in the bin directory by default, but changing that made no difference and I ended up launching the server with arguments which is displayed when I run `mongod --help`.Then I realized I can pass a config file with a `-f` or `--config`.
But even after passing the default config file, it gave me this error.

> Unrecognized option: storage.dbpath

But I had followed the proper YAML syntax which was mentioned [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/).
I tried removing space, adding and all other ways to get it working, but it kept giving me the same error. I tried going by what [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39607107/mongodb-yaml-config-file-unrecognized-optionstorage) post said, but I couldn't get it to work.

Then I tried the same on another device with Linux mint.
But there, the mongodb.cfg file, in /etc/ folder was not following YAML syntax(in windows, the default mongodb.cfg in bin folder followed YAML syntax).Rather a format similar to what I have seen in a .bashrc file.

So this surprised me and I tried out the same format in windows 10 machine. Something like this --

```
dbpath=D:\codes\dbs\dbmongo\data
directoryperdb=true
```

And this time, it worked when I launched mongod using -f flag to mention the cfg file. It worked fine. It took hours for me to find this because I was trying to get it to work with the cfg file with YAML syntax.
This is the default mongod.cfg file in my windows 10 device, which didn't work.

```yaml
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\data
  journal:
    enabled: true
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path:  C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\log\mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

Here's the format in which it worked

```sh
dbpath=D:\codes\dbs\dbmongo\data
directoryperdb=true

logappend=true
logpath=D:\codes\dbs\dbmongo\log\mongod.txt

# network interfaces
#port=27017
bind_ip=127.0.0.1
```

Here you can see that the format which worked uses the same parameters as given in the `mongod --help` and not the YAML syntax mentioned in the official website.
I was wondering if anyone else is facing this issue and how/why YAML cfg file is not working as it should.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/convert-command-line-options-to-yaml/ or this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-file-settings-command-line-options-mapping/

Comment: That is how I was expecting it to work, but instead, I had to give the command line options directly. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not valid YAML syntax and the parameters might be wrong. I think Parameter names are case-sensitive.

It must be like this:

```
storage:
   dbPath: D:\codes\dbs\dbmongo\data
   directoryPerDB: true
```

Comment: Yes, your example is right and follows proper syntax mentioned in the documentation. But in my device, that syntax was throwing errors, therefore I had to resort to entering the parameters(which is a bit different to that mentioned in the official documentation), which is displayed when you type `mongod --help`, but without the `--`. To my surprise, it worked fine.